# Getting my RoR Application Running locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm having real problems trying to install my EngineYard-hoted RoR app on my Mac (for development)

/james-hughess-macbook-2:futology jameshughes$ gem install json
Fetching: json-1.5.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 to the previous comment/question. Development libs and headers are not installed with base OS. Installing XCode will put them there

Comment: It works if you install devkit - devkit takes care of native installations. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Mac, but looks line you need to install header files for Ruby.
http://www.macruby.org/trac/wiki/Troubleshooting